# Add year to Java Calendar doesn't work

Tags: java, calendar

Please enlight me on this :

I'm simply trying to add 10 years to the current date then substract an expiration date from it to return the number of years:

```
public int getMaxYears() {
  int max = 0;
  Calendar ten_year_later = Calendar.getInstance();
  ten_year_later.setTime(new Date());
  ten_year_later.add(Calendar.YEAR, 10);
  Calendar expiration = Calendar.getInstance();
  expiration.setTime(expiration_date);
  max = (int) (ten_year_later.getTimeInMillis() - expiration.getTimeInMillis())/(365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  return max;
}
```

When I debug this, the calendar always stay at the current year.

Anyone ?

Comment: Which calendar?  ten_year_later or expiration?

Comment: @Paul Tomblin : ten_year_later ... I'll edit the question.

Comment: Also: a year isn't 365 days, it has to account for leap years. For rough calculations, 365.25 works, but for real calculations you need something that knows the rules ... like Calendar.

Comment: @Anon : I know. Thanks, but this isn't the question.

Comment: I would suggest using the JodaTime library for all of your date calculation needs.

Comment: Perhaps, but it's merely one of several logical errors in the code. The real point of my comment is that you have a tool for manipulating dates, yet you're trying to manipulate them outside of that tool. See my answer if you want explicit instructions.

Comment: Well, thanks all! My problem wasn't with the Calendar but with the max calculation. Using a long type, as Stacker's answer, solve my problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a problem with int / long conversion: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
Which evaluates to 31536000000 and therefore exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE` 2147483647
This works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
          Calendar ten_year_later = Calendar.getInstance();
          System.out.println( ten_year_later.getTime() );
          ten_year_later.setTime(new Date()); 
          ten_year_later.add(Calendar.YEAR, 10);
          System.out.println( ten_year_later.getTime() );
          Calendar expiration = Calendar.getInstance(); 
          expiration.setTime(expiration.getTime()); 
          long max = (ten_year_later.getTimeInMillis() - expiration.getTimeInMillis())/(365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L); 
          System.out.println( "max " + max );
        }
```

Comment: +1: I think this is better for the case the OP would like to round down on years instead of round up. The OP only have to keep in mind that a year doesn't necessarily have 365 days.

Answer (score 6):

Your calculation of `max` is wrong. An `int` cannot hold a year in millis.

Rather replace it by

```
max = ten_year_later.get(Calendar.YEAR) - expiration.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Or better, use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/):

```
DateTime tenYearsLater = new DateTime().plusYears(10);
DateTime expiration = new DateTime(expiration_date.getTime());
Period period = new Period(expiration, tenYearsLater);
return period.getYears();
```

Comment: This will not work! 2020-01-01 - 2010-12-31 = 10. It should give 9 + 1 day, so 9 years;

Comment: @elblanco: See my comment on stacker's answer.

Comment: +1 I fully agree that it should be calculated as you pointed out.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple example of what should work.

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(new Date());
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, yearsToAdd);
Date retDate = cal.getTime();
```

Just remember to use a long to get the time in milliseconds!

Comment: This is the only working solution for me of all these answers. Thx Bryan!

Answer (score 1):

Calendar is lazy, so it might not recalculate all the other fields until you ask for them.  That's thrown me off in the debugger before.  What happens if you `System.out.println(ten_year_later);`?

Comment: The `getTimeInMillis()` should already have updated the fields -as every other `get` method of `Calendar`.

Comment: Even if I call ten_year_later.getTimeInMillis() ? max is always 0 cause the expiration_date after than today.

Comment: No, I was talking about what you see in the debugger before you call getTimeInMillis().

Answer (score 1):

I've noted in a comment that you have an incorrect calculation for number of millis in a year (nevermind the int/long issue).

Since you have two calendars, each of which can keep a year, why don't you write your code like this (not compiled, so may contain typos):

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.newInstance();   // this will use current time
cal1.add(Calendar.YEAR, 10);
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.newInstance();
cal2.setDate(expiration);
return cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) - cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Assuming that's what you really want ...

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use modern *java.time* classes. Can be done in a one-liner (not that I recommend that).

```
Period
.between(
    ( ( GregorianCalendar) myCalendarExpiration ).toZonedDateTime().toLocalDate() ,
    ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ).plusYears( 10 ).toLocalDate() 
)
.getYears()
```

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the legacy date-time classes such as `Calendar`.

The usual concrete implementation of `Calendar` is `GregorianCalendar`. This is now replaced by `ZonedDateTime`. You can convert back and forth by calling new methods on the old classes.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtExpiration = ( ( GregorianCalendar) myCal ).toZonedDateTime() ;
```

Get current moment.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtNow  = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Add ten years.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtLater = zdtNow.plusYears( 10 ) ;
```

Calculate elapsed time in years between the dates of those two moments.

```
Period p = Period.between(
    zdtExpiration.toLocalDate() , 
    zdtLater.toLocalDate()
) ;
```

Interrogate for the number of full years.

```
int yearsElapsed = p.getYears() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The number of milliseconds in a year is well outside the range of an int, so both the int cast of `ten_year_later.getTimeInMillis() - expiration.getTimeInMillis()` and the calculation `365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` will evaluate to incorrect values.

The `ten_year_later` should be correct. There is no need to invoke computeFields as R. Bemrose wrote.