# store current date and date 1 year from current in java

Tags: java, date

I have everything setup already to store the current date to a variable in Java.  What I am trying to figure out is how to store a date of 1 year after the current date.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Calendar;
```

Here is what I have for the current date:

```
DateFormat newDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = new Date();
startDate = newDate.format(date);
```

So if it were today for example it would store 2/18/2013.  I am trying to store the date 2/18/2014.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What about...2/29/2016?  What's a year from that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add year to Java Calendar doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883167/add-year-to-java-calendar-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

If you do not want to drag external libraries, just use `calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1)`

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date today = cal.getTime();
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1); // to get previous year add -1
Date nextYear = cal.getTime();
```

Note, if the date was `29/Feb/2012` and you added 1 year, you will get `28/Feb/2013`

Comment: How to do the same using Instant? Instant.now().toEpochMilli() gets the us time(long). But how to do as asked in the question using Instant?

Comment: today is not used and you say you add -1 while the code says the opposite

Answer (score 17):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "2/18/2013" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "M/d/uuuu" ) 
).plusYears( 1 )
```

## Details

The [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14946917/642706) is correct, but outdated as of Java 8.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later supplants the troublesome old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. The new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework, intended as its successor, similar in concept but re-architected. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### `LocalDate`

These new classes include [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), to represent a date-only value with no time-of-day nor time zone.

First we must parse the String input. The [java.time formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) uses pattern codes similar to the old classes, but not exactly the same. So be sure to read the new doc carefully.

#### Padded Zero

Notice that your input String lacks leading zero digit for some values. That means you should use single pattern codes, `M` and `d` rather than `MM` and `dd`. Double codes means you expect padding zero to always be included for otherwise single-digit values, `02` rather than `2`.

```
String input = "2/18/2013";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "M/d/uuuu" );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse ( input , formatter );
```

Add a year. The java.time framework takes care of leap year.

```
LocalDate yearLater = localDate.plusYears ( 1 );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "localDate: " + localDate + " and yearLater: " + yearLater );
```

> localDate: 2013-02-18 and yearLater: 2014-02-18

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. Good example of a late answer that can still add tremendous value.

Comment: Dear Down-Voter, please leave a criticism along with your vote.

Answer (score 6):

Use [**Calendar#add(int field, int amount)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) method.You should use Calendar API in-order to manipulate date and time operations.

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance(); 
Calendar nextYearToday = today;
nextYearToday.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date today = cal.getTime();
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1); // to get previous year add 1
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1); // to get previous day add -1
        Date expiryDate = cal.getTime();


        System.out.println("today is --> "+today);
        System.out.println("expiryDate is --> "+expiryDate);
```

**OutPut**
today is --> Fri Dec 01 10:10:52 GMT+05:30 2017

expiryDate is --> Fri Nov 30 10:10:52 GMT+05:30 2018

date today is -> Fri Dec 01 10:10:52 GMT+05:30 2017

expiryDate is -> Fri Nov 30 10:10:52 GMT+05:30 2018

[image]

Comment: FYI, the troublesome `Date` and `Calendar` classes are now legacy, and should be avoided. They are supplanted by the java.time classes built into Java 8 and Java 9. For Java 6 and Java 7, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* project.

Comment: Please help how to check expiry date in java 9 .

Answer (score -2):

In Android is simpler than ever:

`oneYearAfterDate = new Date(date.getTime() + DateUtils.YEAR_IN_MILLIS )`