# Incrementing date (timestamp) got from database by 1 year

Tags: java, date

I am getting the date value from databse through bean. I want to increment the date got from the database by +1 year. 
Can someone please tell me how can I do this?
This is what I have done so far.

```
    if (reviewDate != null || !(reviewDate.equals("0"))) 
                {    
                    //convert reviewDate string to date
                    Date currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(reviewDate);
                    System.out.println("currentDate = "+currentDate);

                    //get the current year
                    int currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
                    int currentDay = currentDate.getDate();
                    long currentYear = currentDate.getYear();
                    long currentTime = currentDate.getTime();   
                    System.out.println("current month="+currentMonth);
                    System.out.println("current day="+currentDay);
                    System.out.println("current year="+currentYear);
                    System.out.println("current time="+currentTime);

                    Date newDate = null;

                    //increment year
                    currentYear = currentYear+1;
                    System.out.println("current year after increment="+currentYear);

                    //add this to currentDate and assign to newDate
                    reviewDate = currentMonth + "/" + currentDay + "/" + currentYear + " " + currentTime;

                    System.out.println("ReviewDate=" + reviewDate);
                }
```

My input is - 04/22/1980 11:30:20
My output should be - 04/22/1981 11:30:20

However, I am getting 3/22/81/325279822000

I think I cannot use calendar because I do not want to increment by current date. Can someone suggest me a working solution for this?

Comment: You can use Calendar, just call with setTime() first.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946886/store-current-date-and-date-1-year-from-current-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this way

```
 String rDate="04/22/1980 11:30:20"; // your received String date
 DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");// date format
 Date date=df.parse(rDate);// parse String to date
 Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTime(date); // set calender instance to date value
 calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR,1); // add one year to current
 System.out.println(df.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Out put:

```
 04/22/1981 11:30:20
```

About `Java` [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here is Java 8 solution by [`java.time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html):

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;


public class SO25801191 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getDateAsStringIncrementedByYear("04/22/1980 11:30:20", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 1));
    }

    private static String getDateAsStringIncrementedByYear(String inputDateStr, String pattern, long yearsToIncrement) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(inputDateStr, formatter);      
        return dateTime.plusYears(yearsToIncrement).format(formatter);
    }
}
```