# How to get today's date in java if system date is one year back of current date?

Tags: java

My motive is to get current date without caring of the system date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [store current date and date 1 year from current in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946886/store-current-date-and-date-1-year-from-current-in-java)

Comment: @Daniel it's not duplicate. OP is asking how to get correct date if system date is set to invalid date like 1 year back.

Comment: What sources do you have that you can ask for the correct time?

Comment: may be get the date from your database (I see sql-server tag here)

Answer (score 6):

My suggestion, if you *really* can't rely on the system time is to use a time server.  Apache commons has a really useful client which will help with the this.  There are plenty of examples online:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ntp/NTPUDPClient.html

There are also numerous available timeservers.

Don't be tempted to just correct the date yourself in the code, this will be fragile and will break if someone corrects the server time.

The obvious, and easier, solution is to correct the time on the server though!

Answer (score 0):

## Time Server

Access a [time server](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_server)  over the Internet. Have your app contact that local time server to query the current time.

Or, set up a [time server](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_server) on your local network. Consider placing that time server computer in [network’s DMZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29) so as to get updates from time servers on the Internet such as the [pool.ntp.org project](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi) or [those provided by the United States federal government (NIST)](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi).

## Radio Clock

Obtain a [radio clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_clock) with a [USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) connection for output of current time  synchronized by a time code transmitted by a radio transmitter connected to a time standard such as an atomic clock. Transmitters are broadcasting in many countries all over the world.

The [Meinberg Global](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/) company, at least, offers [several such devices](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/products/usb-clocks.htm).

[image: photo of a couple of radio clock via USB devices]

## GPS

Similar to the radio clocks above, a receiver of GPS ([Global Positioning System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System)) signals might also capture and relay the [time signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_signal). Or perhaps [GALILEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_(satellite_navigation)) or [GLONASS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLONASS).

[image]

## Sundial

Position a [sundial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sundial) outside a window. Attach a [webcam](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webcam) to the computer in question. Position the webcam in the window. Write an app to interpret the time of day from current image of the sundial.

Caveat: Not practical in Seattle.

[image: photo of a sundial on a pedestal in a garden]

---

## `java.time.Clock`

To harness any of these suppliers of the current moment, write a subclass of the abstract [`java.time.Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) class.

You can pass your `Clock` implementation as an argument to the various *java.time* methods. For example, [`Instant.now( clock )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now-java.time.Clock-).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now( yourClockGoesHere ) ;
```

For testing purposes, note the alternate implementations of `Clock` available statically from `Clock` itself: [`fixed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#fixed-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-), `offset`, `tick`, and more.

Avoid the legacy date-time classes from the earliest versions of Java, such as `Date` & `Calendar`. These troublesome classes are entirely supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).